# Multiple instances of mediawiki on stand alone server

Tags: mediawiki

I want to run a second instance of MediaWiki on a stand alone server. Does anyone have a guide on how to do this without causing problems for my current MediaWiki instance.

Comment: What sort of problems are you anticipating?

Comment: I'm afraid of conflicts with the current installation

Comment: Why? It's a standalone server. How would it conflict?

Comment: Listening on the same port, database etc. Just wondering if someone has done it before and has pointers on how to avoid potential pitfalls

Comment: @SystemsParty: It's clear from your comment that you have no idea how mediawiki and a web server is configured. Please familiarize yourself with how to configure your web server of choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to deploy literally thousands of instances on the same server. How this is done depends on the kind of server software you are using and how it is configured, which you don't tell.

Basically, you can either configure additional vhosts like `wiki1.example.com` or use subdirs like `http://example.com/wiki1`. Then you have to make sure the databases don't conflict. For this, you can either create a new database per wiki or use table name prefixes (which you can specifiy in the base config for each instance).

What is best depends on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, sounds like I should just install it again and create a new DB if I want to get it done quickly